# Concurrency Thread Group plugin - where is source code?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I've been using custom plugins for JMeter:

https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=random-csv

https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-casutg

I wanted to see the code, maybe improve a thing for myself and maybe others too.

For 1st on the page link goes to GitHub with code. But for the second (Custom Thread Groups), link points to https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/, where there is only a description.

Web search finds maven repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-casutg/2.9 which have `jar` file. Surely it is said about open-source for JMeter, not plugins:

> Custom Plugins for Apache JMeter™ This project is an independent set
>   of plugins for Apache JMeter, the popular Open-Source load and
>   performance testing tool.

So are `Custom Thread Groups` open source and if yes, where can I see the code? If not open-source, what is the licence for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's part of JMeter (casutg) plugin, found in package [com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/tree/133315ac97244d78423d24c7330f5cabd7d6efc5/plugins/casutg/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/threads/concurrency)

> ConcurrencyThreadGroup.java
>
> ConcurrencyThreadGroupGui.java
>
> ConcurrencyThreadStarter.java

JMeter plugin license is [Apache License 2.0](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/LICENSE)

> A permissive license whose main conditions require preservation of copyright and license notices.

See more about [Apache license](https://resources.whitesourcesoftware.com/blog-whitesource/top-10-apache-license-questions-answered):

> Apache License is a permissive **open source** software license

Comment: Very interesting way to distinguish *inhouse* and "open source", even more interesting is providing [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter/). Both are from the same vendor and both are open source.

Comment: @DmitriT thanks, updated, I was confused with other plugin